# How to plot data approaching zero in pgfplots log plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to generate a log plot of some data using `pgfplots`. I've mostly got it looking how I want, but I'd like the plot to show the data continuing down toward the origin rather than stopping at the `x=0.05` datapoint.

I've tried adding an `extra ytick` for 0, and it horribly distorts the look of things, as expected. I also tried adding a "fake" data point (for which I could remove the dot(?)) in approximately the right place on the plot, but this is tedious, error-prone, and [frankly] dishonest.

I have made great strides with LaTeX through internet searches. However, in this case my google-fu fails me.

How can I get the plot to extend toward the origin (while the origin remains "offscreen")? To be clear, I would like the x/y windowing to remain how it is -- I just want the plot to continue to the edge rather than stopping at the `x=0.05` datapoint.

This code is probably a mess, so I apologize in advance for anything in here that's done in a terrible way.

```latex
\begin {figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$v_D$ (\si{\volt})},
        ylabel={$i_D$ (\si{\ampere})},
        ytick={0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001},
        yticklabels={$\SI{10}{\nano\ampere}$, $\SI{100}{\nano\ampere}$, $\SI{1}{\micro\ampere}$, $\SI{10}{\micro\ampere}$, $\SI{100}{\micro\ampere}$, $\SI{1}{\milli\ampere}$},
        ymode=log,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        legend pos=outer north east,
    ]

        \addplot table{
-1.000  -1.429E-08
0   0.000E+00
0.05    2.343E-08
0.10    8.547E-08
0.15    2.497E-07
0.20    6.842E-07
0.25    1.831E-06
0.30    4.843E-06
0.35    1.265E-05
0.40    3.227E-05
0.45    7.824E-05
0.50    1.726E-04
0.55    3.340E-04
0.60    5.646E-04
0.65    8.532E-04
0.70    1.210E-03
        };
        \addlegendentry{$i_D$}

        % diagonal extension line
        \addplot[mark=none, black, dotted, line width = 1] coordinates {
            (0, 2E-08) (0.45,7.824E-05)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Finding $I_S$}
\label{fig:3_is}
\end {figure}
```

[image: Screenshot of plot output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no time now to derive the diode equation parameters , but what about this?

You just substitute the correct current value for the point at $V_D=\SI{0.01}{V}$ (btw, $v_{\scriptscriptstyle D}$ looks better ;-), I even have a macro for it).

Then  you manually fix the range (`xmin=0, xmax=0.6, enlarge x limits, ymin=1e-8, ymax=4e-3`) and plot (I added `smooth` but that's a matter of taste).

The key `enlarge x limits` is used to have the same effect as the "expanded" x-axis you have.

The part of the graph going outside is automatically clipped (look at the description of the key `clip mode`).

Obviously, you can do the same on the other side (add one value for 0.9 V, for example).

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=0.7, enlarge x limits,
        ymin=1e-8, ymax=4e-3,
        xlabel={$v_D$ (\si{\volt})},
        ylabel={$i_D$ (\si{\ampere})},
        ytick={0.00000001, 0.0000001, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001},
        yticklabels={$\SI{10}{\nano\ampere}$, $\SI{100}{\nano\ampere}$, $\SI{1}{\micro\ampere}$, $\SI{10}{\micro\ampere}$, $\SI{100}{\micro\ampere}$, $\SI{1}{\milli\ampere}$},
        ymode=log,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        ]
        % first point added semi-"randomly", substitute the correct value
        \addplot+[smooth] table{
                0.01    4.0E-09
                0.05    2.343E-08
                0.10    8.547E-08
                0.15    2.497E-07
                0.20    6.842E-07
                0.25    1.831E-06
                0.30    4.843E-06
                0.35    1.265E-05
                0.40    3.227E-05
                0.45    7.824E-05
                0.50    1.726E-04
                0.55    3.340E-04
                0.60    5.646E-04
                0.65    8.532E-04
                0.70    1.210E-03
            };
        \addlegendentry{$i_D$}

            % diagonal extension line
            % just to show that you can use TikZ normal drawing commands here
            \draw[mark=none, black, dotted, line width = 1] 
                    (0, 2E-08) -- (0.45,7.824E-05);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great. I appreciate your explanation, pointing me to the right search term for more information, and additional suggestions. Thanks!